# Call method on object via invokeScriptAsync

Tags: javascript, winjs

I am working on a WinJS project and trying to use the invokeScriptAsync to call a method on a x-ms-webview.  It is not working and the error I am getting is not helpful. I am only getting an "Unknown Error."  I have never had any problems before, the only difference this time is the method I am calling is part of any object rather than a global javascript method.  My call looks something like this:

```
webview.invokeScriptAsync("object.subobject1.subobject2.method", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3").start();
```

The only thing I can think of is that the function has to be a global, but I haven't found any documentation to support that.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I have been able to make calling methods on an object work is by passing eval to the invokeScriptAsync method:

```
webview.invokeScriptAsync("eval", "object.subobject1.subobject2.method('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3');").start();
```

Comment: I ended up refactoring things so that my method was in the global object.  This does however answer my original question.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to [invokeScriptAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn301841.aspx) is a string, which gets resolved within the webview. What you're doing is attempting to resolve the variable object.subobject1.subobject2.method in the app's JavaScript content, which will likely be "undefined". Hence asking the webview to execute undefined gives you an obscure error.

Wrap the function name you're calling in quotes, and it will then get resolved in the script context of the webview:

```
webview.invokeScriptAsync("object.subobject1.subobject2.method", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3").start();
```

In short, think of invokeScriptAsync like you would eval.

Comment: I will update my question, I was passing the first argument as a string, just forgot the quotes

Comment: And the function in the Webview does need to be in the global scope, to answer your other question. Also, have you tried working with scenario 5 of the HTML Webview control sample (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HTML-WebView-control-sample-56e773fa), which uses invokeScriptAsync? That's your basic reference that should work, and you can try modifying it with your function and find the glitch.

Comment: I changed my function to call a globally scoped function and it is working fine now.  It's not as clean but it is working.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Keeping the global scope clean is one reason why the WinJS library added WinJS.Namespace.define. This basically lets you cleanly define a top-level namespace variable off of which you can hang any number of other members. If you use such namespaces inside the webview's code, then you can use those names with invokeScriptAsync. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br212667.aspx. You can load WinJS into a Webview too (it's written for that), and if you want a minimal variant with just little bits, see https://github.com/winjs/winjs-modules.